# How to find database name of \data\base postgres folders?

Tags: postgresql

I have a large folder of 70 GB in my postgres installation under:

`D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data\base\130205`

Question: how could I find out which database is based on that folder?
I have like 10 databases running on the same server, and most of them having a tablespace on a different drive.

But probably I'm missing a mapping somewhere, maybe a large index or kind of. How can I find out the "causing" database of these amounts of data?

Comment: The number is the oid of the database: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-file-layout.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the hint of @a_horse, the following statement shows the oid and table names:

`SELECT oid,* from pg_database`

Answer (score 1):

Just run `oid2name` as PostgreSQL operating system user.

Comment: Where is this command?  I am running 9.5.20 and I get command not found at the bash prompt as postgres user.

Comment: It is where your PostgreSQL binaries are installed. You probably don't have it on your `PATH`, so you need to call it with its absolute path.

Comment: Was about to say it's not there but I've just found it - it's at `/usr/bin/oid2name`.  For some reason my pg binaries are in `/usr/bin` .. I just saw eg pgbench in /usr/bin and lo! there's oid2name and a bunch of other stuff too.  Thanks.

Comment: @JL_SO So how could you miss it? Surely `/usr/bin` is on your path...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to find the size of your largest databases (taken from [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage)):

```
SELECT d.datname AS Name,  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) AS Owner,
    CASE WHEN pg_catalog.has_database_privilege(d.datname, 'CONNECT')
        THEN pg_catalog.pg_size_pretty(pg_catalog.pg_database_size(d.datname))
        ELSE 'No Access'
    END AS SIZE
FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d
    ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN pg_catalog.has_database_privilege(d.datname, 'CONNECT')
        THEN pg_catalog.pg_database_size(d.datname)
        ELSE NULL
    END DESC -- nulls first
    LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Running this gives: `ERROR: could not stat file "base/24593/146476": Permission denied SQL state: 42501`

Comment: You probably need to run it as the db administrator.

Comment: You need to deactivate the virus scanner for the PostgreSQL data directory.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this syntax. it takes the ID and the name of the database from the pg_databse.

```
$ select pg_database.datname,pg_database.oid from pg_database;
```