# Postgresql unique installation id

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Where can I get Postgresql unique installation ID?
like...

`SELECT dbid from v$database;` (in oracle)

I need it to identify my different database installation across different sites.
Getting MAC id of server is a way but if there is a way to get it from postgresql it would be preferred.

Comment: Is this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39464650/how-to-find-database-name-of-data-base-postgres-folders you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

if you have replication slot available, [you can use](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-replication.html) `IDENTIFY_SYSTEM`:

```
MacBook-Air:~ vao$ psql "dbname=postgres replication=database" -c "IDENTIFY_SYSTEM;"
Timing is on.
Pager usage is off.
      systemid       | timeline |  xlogpos   |  dbname
---------------------+----------+------------+----------
 6401169876745218982 |        1 | 1/7A470D80 | postgres
(1 row)
```